# Integrating StartApp SDK into RoboVM application?

Tags: sdk, robovm, startapp

I wrote an ios application with robovm and I want to integrate StartApp SDK to it . However , I can't find StartApp SDK for robovm . So , how should I do . Please help me , thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add StartApp IOS SDK, you will need to create a binding project first. There is a GitHub repo from some folks of the libGDX / RoboVM community that already has the bindings for a lot of popular SDKs,

You can find the repo, and the binding creation guide [**here**](https://github.com/BlueRiverInteractive/robovm-ios-bindings#how-do-i-create-a-binding).

Comment: Thanks for your support . However , I found a binding of Mopub for Robovm . Should I use it ? If I can use it , how should I use it ?

Comment: You can use the mopub binding, but i'm afraid you will need to create the StartApp binding anyway, because based on the wiki, mopub binding supports this networks: AdColony (SDK Version: 2.4.10)
AppLovin (SDK Version: 2.5.3)
Chartboost (SDK Version: 5.0.2)
Conversant (SDK Version: 4.3.0)
Facebook Audience Network (SDK Version: 3.18)
Google Mobile Ads (SDK Version: 6.12.0)
iAd
InMobi (SDK Version: 4.4.1)
RevMob (SDK Version: 7.5.5)
Vungle (SDK Version: 3.0.10)